# How to select the specific table of webpage with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am newbie in programming and python. But I want to parse HTML in my python script.

Here is the webpage:
http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00759.html

**Question 1**:

This page is about the financial information of particular share. These four tables is about:

1. financial summary,
2. Balance Sheet,
3. Cash Flow
4. Income Statement.

And I want to extract the information in table 3 & 4. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00759.html'

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()   #.read() mean read all into a string
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

table = soup.find("table", { "class" : "tab05" })
for row in table.findAll("tr"):
    print row.findAll("td")
```

But this code only can get the first table information. How can I change the code in order to get the third and fourth table information? I found that those 4 tables do not contain unique id or classname, I dont know how to locate them....

**Question 2:**

Also this is simplify Chinese webpage, how to keep the original text on output?

**Question 3:**

On the upper right corner of each table, there is a drop down menu for selecting the appropriated period, namely: **"All"**, **"Whole Year"**, **"Half Year"**, **"First Quarter"** and **"Third Quarter"**. Is `urllib` able to change this drop down menu?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

According to the website, all four tables have the class name "tab05".

Therefore, all you have to do is simply change the `.find` method to `.findAll` at the var `soup`, then all four table can be accessed.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://stock.finance.sina.com.cn/hkstock/finance/00759.html'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

tables = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "tab05" })
print len(tables) #4

for table in tables:
    for row in table.findAll("tr"):
        for col in row.findAll("td"):
            print col.getText()
```

As for the encoding of simplify Chinese, `print col.getText()` will get the right words on the terminal. If you are seeking for writing them to a file, you have to encode the string to gb2312.

```
f.write(col.getText().encode('gb2312'))
```

For the 3rd question, since the data are rendered by javascript function written in datatable.js, I think it is not possible to get all of them simply by urllib. Better check out some other library to find a suitable usage.

Comment: Thanks.
I may be misunderstand your meaning. I rewrite the code but I cannot get all information of that table. The last figure got from this code is "-45.7852", which is only the half of that table.

Comment: That is strange... Mine shows that   >>> table = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "tab05" })   >>> len(table)   >>> 4

Comment: Please rerun html = urllib.urlopen(url).read() again to make sure it is not a connection problem.

Comment: Yes, I have rerun the code again, And the result has been captured and uploaded to http://postimg.org/image/j5g6pfpmx/

The no of tables is only 1, and the figure is incompleted...

Comment: The len(html) is 83639, I believed the connection is fine.

And my Beautifulsoup is downloaded from:
http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/BeautifulSoup.py

Comment: Thanks for yr help. I find the problem:
if i use "from bs4 import BeautifulSoup", I only got 1 table
if i use "from BeautifulSoup import *"(I install BeautifulSoup by easy_install: easy_install BeautifulSoup), I can get 4 tables, But print col.getText() cannot get the right words

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply.
I may be misunderstand your meaning. I rewrite the code as following:

```
tables = soup.findAll("table", { "class" : "tab05" })

print len(tables)

for row in tables[0].findAll("tr"):
    for col in row.findAll("td"):
        print col.getText()
```

The result of "len(tables)" is  1. Only the first table can be accessed.
Also I found that if I use

```
for row in tables[0].findAll("tr"):
    for col in row.findAll("td"):
```

I cannot get all information of that table. The last figure got from this code is "-45.7852", which is only the half of that table.